# document.ElementID('id').innerHTML = goes only blinks once and then it's gone

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a small piece of code I'm writing.  Essentially I'm taking a custom formed string and turning it into json.  It works but the part where I wrote to a  it just blinks on the page and is gone.  When I put the document.getElementId..... outside the function call it says undefined.  Any thoughts on how to combat this?

```
Input like:
    pizzas@size:"large";toppings:sausage
<form name="form1" onsubmit="getString()">
    <input type="text" name="txtJob" id="txtJob" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<p id="myJson"></p>
<script>
    var myString, w, tableName, x;
    function getString(){
        myString = document.getElementById("txtJob").value;
        w = myString.split("@");
        tableName = w[0];
        alert(tableName);
        x = w[1].split(";");
        myLength = x.length-1;
        document.getElementById("myJson").innerHTML=
        '<h1>'+ tableName + '</h1>';
    }

</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Helps if you make a fiddle for us: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/tBScz/

Comment: because page reloads when you submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's disappearing because once the form submits, it reloads the page. The solution is to `return false` from the `onsubmit` handler. This prevents the default action (submitting) from taking place. e.g.,

```
<form name="form1" onsubmit="getString();return false;">
    <input type="text" name="txtJob" id="txtJob" value="pizzas@size:&quot;large&quot;;toppings:sausage">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<p id="myJson"></p>
<script>
    var myString, w, tableName, x;
    function getString(){
        myString = document.getElementById("txtJob").value;
        w = myString.split("@");
        tableName = w[0];
        alert(tableName);
        x = w[1].split(";");
        myLength = x.length-1;
        document.getElementById("myJson").innerHTML=
        '<h1>'+ tableName + '</h1>';

    }

</script>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/tBScz/1/)